# Get number of weak_ptr objects that point to resource

Tags: caching, c++11, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

I am trying to create a custom cashing mechanism where I am returning a `weak_ptr` to the cache created. Internally, I hold a `shared_ptr` to control the lifetime of the object.

When the maximum cache pre-set is consumed, the disposer looks for those cache objects that are not accessed for a long time and will clean them up.

Unfortunately this may not be ideal. If it was possible to check how many cache objects can be accessed through the `weak_ptr`, then this can be a criteria for making the decision to clean up or not.

Turns out there is no way to check how many `weak_ptr(s)` have handle to the resource.

But when I look at the `shared_ptr` documentation and implementation notes

=> the number of `weak_ptrs` that refer to the managed object

is part of the implementation. Why is this not exposed through an API ?

Comment: Turns out that it is impossible to implement std::shared_ptr without knowing the collection of std::weak_ptr tracking the same memory resource. Therefore I have started a thread at the ISOCPP forum for getting this feature. Hopefully C++17 will have this as a part of the standard.